# Read txt file with missing "new lines"

Tags: php

Having log file with missing "new line" from time to time

```
2010.12.17 04:26    127.0.0.1   user:user1  region:NA   ERROR: Invalid password
2010.12.17 04:27    127.0.0.1   user:user1  region:AP   ERROR: Invalid password
2010.12.17 04:32    127.0.0.12010.12.17 04:32   127.0.0.1   user:user1  region:AP   ERROR: Invalid password
2010.12.17 04:32    127.0.0.1   user:user1  region:NA   ERROR: Invalid password
```

In the example above in the 3rd line:

`2010.12.17 04:32    127.0.0.1` should be in a line

and `2010.12.17 04:32    127.0.0.1    user:user1  region:AP   ERROR: Invalid password` should be in another line.

I need to read the lines into an array, like file() is doing, but with corrected lines.

I cannot touch the file itself to correct it by inserting new lines where needed.

I was thinking about fread, but that would read the whole file content into a single string. Maybe I should parse this big string..?

Do you have a better idea how to achieve that?

Comment: How big is the file? Can you read it in memory?

Comment: now it's ~2mb.. but I have other files that could be bigger..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can load the whole file into memory, you can use `preg_split()` based on what the start of a line looks like:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?=\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})/m', $body);

print_r($result); // ignore first array element
```

Comment: thanks! that works so far. Could you please explain every regex section?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a way of detecting where these newlines are expected, so that you may read data up to these places. This means that you need to look into the file line format, and try to base your reading on that format. The simplest way is to use a regex, which will try to match as much text as possible until that pattern which starts the next line. The match should take in account the possible existence of a end of line marker.

Luckily, each line of the log starts with a timestamp, which should not vary much accross the file. Usually, logs covers one day, so you could base you regexp on the first chars of the log, which must be the beginning of the first line.

```
$file = fopen($logname, "r");    
$content = array();
$date = fread($file, 9); // date length
fseek($file, 0);
$pattern = $date.".*?(".$date.")?";
while ($data = fread($file, 4096)){
    $buff .= $data;
    while (preg_match($pattern, $data,$matches = array())){
        $content[] = $matches[0];
        $buff = substr($buff, strlen($matches[0]));
    }
} // end of file
if (strlen($buff)){
    echo ”extra data at end of log : " . $buff;
}
```

You should be able to tune that code according to your log timestamp format.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jack's answer, wrote a code that uses fopen and fgets: fgets reads line by line, I guess it does not load the memory as when using file() or fread().

```
    $flog_path="/srv/www/****.log";
    $ftemp = fopen($flog_path,"r");
    while ($s=fgets($ftemp)) {
        $elem=preg_split('/(?=\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})/m', $s);
        foreach (array_filter($elem) as $v) $result[] = trim($v);
    }
```